# Discrete maths Equivalence relations and classes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

**How do i do this?**

Let the natural number N be our universe. We start by defining the property P(q) :
q is even. We define the relation R on N as follows: ∀n,m (n, m) ∈ R iff P(n + m).

a) Show that R is an equivalence relation.

b) Can you determine how many equivalence classes the relation R has?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get help rather than downvotes and votes to close if you [edit] the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck. Write down some pairs $(m,n)$ where $P(m+n)$ is true and where it is false. See if you detect a pattern. Then look at the definition of "equivalence relation".

Comment: Hey, thanks for the feedback. I'm fairly new to discrete maths, and equivalende relation, so i'm not quite sure how to go forward with the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (a)

First, instantiate n and m to be arbitrary in $N$ (which gets rid of the forall quantifier). After that, you go over the definition of an equivalence relation and prove that the conditions hold one by one. Namely:

$(n,n) \in R$. (Reflexivity) (here, we don't even use the m, which is fine as we chose arbitrary n, m) This proof is trivial and I assume you can do that on your own (hint: x + x = 2*x)

$(n,m) \in R \iff (m,n) \in R $ (Symmetry).

**Proof for symmetry:**

$(\Rightarrow)$ Ass.: $(n,m) \in R$. Hence, $n + m \equiv_2 0$. By commutativity of $+$ operator, we know that $n + m = m + n$, from which directly follows that $m + n \equiv_2 0$
You argue that addition is symmetric, i.e. if $n + m \equiv_2 0$ so is $m + n \equiv_2 0$. Hence, $(m,n) \in R$

$(\Leftarrow)$ Indirect proof. Ass.: $(n,m) \not\in R$. By identical reasoning, it is clear that $(m,n) \not\in R$. By indirect proof, it follows that $(m,n) \in R \Rightarrow (n,m) \in R$

To show transitivity, you need to chose another arbitrary, fixed $p \in N$ and show:

$(n,p) \in R \ \land \ (p,m) \in R \Rightarrow (n,m) \in R$.

You could do a case distinction based on if $p \equiv_2 0$ and $p \not\equiv_2 0$.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand this right, reflexivity can easily be proven by _(n,n)_ where _n_ is any _N_, and holds true for _P(n+n)_ is even?

Then symmetry by assuming _n = m_?

Comment: Not sure if I fully get your question. A relation $R$ being reflexive **on a set A** (or universe if you want) means that $\forall a \in A. (a,a) \in R$. The "on a set A" part is key here, because a relation can be reflexive for a set $A$ but not on a set $B$. Let's say we have: $R := \{ (1,1); (1,2); (2,1); (2,2)\}$ with sets $A := \{1,2\}$, $B := \{1,2,3\}$. You can just go over $A$ and see that $\forall a \in A. (a,a) \in R$. Conversly, for Set $B$, $\exists b \in B. (b,b) \not\in R$, namely $b := 3$. Hence, $R$ is NOT reflexive on set $B$

Comment: Okei i understand what you mean. But in this case we can say that _R_ is reflexive on the set _N_ because ∀ _n ∈ N (n,n) ∈ R_ since _n+n_ is even right?

Comment: Correct, because $n + n = 2 * n$ and $2 * n \equiv_2 0$

Comment: Do you use $≡_2 0$  to suggest something is even?

Comment: Correct! It's a congruence symbol, $x \equiv_n y$ means that $x % n$ has value $y$.